# How to find $f(777)$ for a particular function $f$?

Tags: functions, problem-solving

A function $f$, defined on the set of positive integers, has $f(1) = 2$ and $f(2) = 3$.

Also $f(f(f(n))) = n + 2$ if $n$ is even and $f(f(f(n))) = n + 4$ if $n$ is odd.

> What is $f(777)$?

I'm not sure where to start. I've tried looking for a pattern by finding that $f(3) = 5, f(4) = 7, f(5) = 4, f(6) = 11, f(7) = 9, f(9) = 6,$ etc. This doesn't seem to lead anywhere. I was also wondering about how if I find the value of $n$ for $f(777) = f(f(f(n)))$ that could give me the answer. Still unclear how I will find this though.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Why don't you try this for $n=3,4,5,\ldots$ and so on and try to find a pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start. I've tried looking for a pattern by finding f(3) = 5, f(4) = 7, f(5) = 4, f(6) = 11, f(7) = 9, f(9) = 6, etc. This doesn't seem to lead anywhere. I was also wondering about how if I find the value of n for f(777) = f(f(n)) that could give me the answer. Still unclear how I will find this though. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: If you continue the chain of values you give for $20$ or $30$, then sort them so the argument of the function is in order, you may see a pattern.  I find a pattern that one could presumably prove by induction.

Comment: Just for fun here's a Matlab code that will give you the answer:
$$ \mathrm{
f=zeros(1,780);\\
f(1)=2;\\f(2)=3;\\
i=3;\\
while \ i<778\\
k=find(f==i);\\
j=find(f==k);\\
if \ mod(j,2) == 0\\
f(i)=j+2;\\
else\\
f(i)=j+4;\\
end\\
i=f(i);\\
end\\
f(777)}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ve seen how to calculate the first few values of $f$ after the two that you were given, e.g.,

$$f(3)=f(f(2))=f(f(f(1)))=1+4=5\;,$$

$$f(5)=f(f(3))=f(f(f(2)))=2+2=4\;,$$

and

$$f(4)=f(f(5))=f(f(f(3)))=3+4=7\;.$$

If you list the first few values **in the order in which they were obtained**, you get

$$\color{red}2,3,5,\color{red}4,7,9,\color{red}6,11,13,\color{red}8,15,17,\color{red}{10}\;.$$

This does show a pattern, which I’ve tried to emphasize by giving the even and odd numbers different colors. You may also notice that this sequence of numbers obeys a rather simple recurrence: if we call the $n$-th number $a_n$, we have

$$a_n=\begin{cases}
a_{n-3}+4,&\text{if }a_{n-3}\text{ is odd}\\
a_{n-3}+2,&\text{if }a_{n-3}\text{ is even.}
\end{cases}$$

It’s possible to use this information to determine $n$ such that $a_n=777$, and from that with a bit of work you can get $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$.